# Using switch statements, with terminating char, in this case '='

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm working on a program that takes in values and operands and calculates the total of said values. This program will loop until the user enters '='.

I believe I am close but am missing something to make it function correctly. Most likely I don't need the while loop but I am unsure.

Example of user input:

```
'6'
'+'
'5'
'-'
'3'
'-'
'7'
'='
```

Total is 1.

```
int main()
{
    float num1, num2;
    char change;
    float total;

    cout << "Welcome to your friendly neighborhood accumulator! Please input your expression, starting with an operand and type in  '='  when completed." << endl;
    

    while(change != '='){       
        cin >> num1;
        cin >> change;
        cin >> num2;

        switch(change){
            case '+':
                total = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                total = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '=':
                cout << total;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Incorrect operator";
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Thank you for using the accumulator!" << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1+2-3 and your `-` will be in num1 not in `change`. Put `num1` out of loop.

Comment: *"I believe I am close but am missing something to make it function correctly,"* -- you are missing several somethings. Pick one symptom, focus on that, **and describe the symptom**. Simplify your code to isolate the symptom from your other issues.

Comment: Thank you, that nearly fixed it. Now I just need to figure out what to do with num2. As I need to enter = twice because it still asks for the second variable after the change is set to '='

Comment: Try to think logically about the steps you need to take in order to solve the problem. For example, the *second* time that you  want to read an operation, do you want to read in `num1` before that `change`? No, you do not; you instead want to use the value *from the previous calculation*. You *only* read a value for the left-hand side *the first time*.  So, try to think about how to structure the logic to reflect that.

Comment: You may find it helps to take pen and paper and draw a flowchart. What steps are inside the loop? Therefore, what should the loop look like in code?

Comment: Thank you all for the help and constructive criticism. I successfully ran the program, and I agree I should've done a flow chart beforehand.  Here is my loop for anyone else who has a similar problem. 'while(change != '='){ 
  cin >> change;
  if(change != '='){
   cin >> num2;
  }
  switch(change){
   case '+':
    total = total + num2;
    break;
   case '-':
    total = total - num2;
    break;
   case '=':
    cout << total << endl;
    break;
   default:
    cout << "Incorrect operator";
    break;
  }
 }'

Answer (score -1):

```
while(change != '='){   
    cin >> change;
    if(change != '='){
        cin >> num2;
    }
    switch(change){
        case '+':
            total = total + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            total = total - num2;
            break;
        case '=':
            cout << total << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Incorrect operator";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how the code you've shown solves the OP's problem.